# Angular 5 Nested *ngFor-Loop with Chunks

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

I'm quite new to Angular and trying to fetch a nested For-Loop as chunks.

```
<div *ngFor="let eventChunks of chunks(events,3);">
      <div *ngFor="let event of eventChunks" class="card-columns">
        <event-item [event]="event"></event-item>
      </div>
```

In my component I have defined the function chunks() as the following:

```
chunks(array, size) {
        let results = [];
        results = [];
        while (array.length) {
            results.push(array.splice(0, size));
        }
        return results;
    };
```

Which ends up in following error:

```
ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ngForOf: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]'. Current value: 'ngForOf: '.
```

Does anyone know how to solve this properly? I tried using TrackBy and index but couldn't find a working solution.

Thank you very much for your time and help! :)

Comment: What does `chunks ` reuturn?

Comment: Results is populating as expected. By console.log before results is returned I get an array with arrays of the size I want to have...

Comment: And logging the returned chunks themself are object arrays of the size I want them...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It's never a good idea to call function for manipulate data from
>   template side

Error is coz of the calling `function` from the template side and that causes the `ngFor` and template rerender (and that causes the loops again),

**In Template Side** Instead of :

```
<div *ngFor="let eventChunks of chunks(events,3);">
```

Just Use

```
<div *ngFor="let eventChunks of events">
```

And **From Component Side** :

Withing constructor / ngOnInit  place this code ( Or within service from you are fetching data )

```
this.events = this.chunks(this.events,3);
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-array-chunk2)** (For More Detail **[Read](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4)**)

Comment: But in fact I only want to manipulate it to change it for the view, so that I can insert other rows between them. Even though not a good idea to change it at that place? Because apart of that I think the usual array seems to be better... ?

Comment: @Ass , You can also add other row by given demo , As I have just called function from component instead of template , What is that you can't achive with this way , will you please explain ?

Comment: It's working as expected, I was thinking about that, too. I only felt not completely satisfied on the first run because I break a beautiful straight array into chunks just to displaying it... i dont really know why^^